# WPF Listbox add item without scrolling

Tags: wpf

Given a WPF ListBox with a vertical scrollbar that uses databinding, is there a way to get it to **not** scroll when items are added to the bound collection?

Use case: User is scrolled down the list to an item and is reading it. New item is added to the head of the bound collection. Listbox should not scroll or otherwise "jump".

Currently, when I add an item to the head of the collection, the listbox scrolls the text down one item.

Comment: check if this does the trick 

ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"

Comment: No, that's not it. But it is an interesting setting I did not know about.

Comment: i'm so late, but see this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774518/when-i-insert-item-in-listbox-my-screen-also-move