# When i insert item in ListBox, my screen also move

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollbar, scrollviewer

Same with the subject, When i add some item in ListBox, also Listbox's Scroll Bar is moved automatically.

Because verticalOffset is same, but ExtraHeight is enlarged.

I Just want Don't move scrollBar when i insert some item...

I use both of ObservableCollection's Insert(0, Object) method and Add() method

The Symptom appears when VerticalOffSet is not 0 nor max Height.
You can see that like below

[image: Before Insert Item] →
[image: After Insert Item]

And i already moved it manually(with Code)
But when i move it original position, I should watch the move animation.

Did you have an idea?

Plz know me about that.

Comment: @MichaelRandall i don't use 2 list box

Comment: Yup, i just reread the question, carry on

Comment: ok, problem is that just my scroll bar is moved when i insert item in my listbox..
i just want see the current(not changed) screen!

Comment: @charleskim I think. You need to handle `RequestBringIntoView` for that kind of behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF the `ItemsControl` maintains the scroll offset relative to the beginning of the list, forcing items in the viewport to move down when items are added to the `ItemsSource`. UWP allows to customize this behavior e.g. to behave the way you need it.

I recommend to extend `ListBox` or alternatively create an attached behavior.

The following example extends `ListBox` and handles the internal `ScrollViewer` to adjust the scroll offset to keep the first visible item in the viewport when items are added to the ItemsSource:

```
class KeepItemsInViewListBox : ListBox
{
  private ScrollViewer ScrollViewer { get; set; }

  #region Overrides of FrameworkElement

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    if (TryFindVisualChildElement(this, out ScrollViewer scrollViewer))
    {
      this.ScrollViewer = scrollViewer;
    }
  }

  #endregion

  #region Overrides of ListView

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnItemsChanged(e);

    if (this.ScrollViewer == null)
    {
      return;
    }

    double verticalOffset;
    switch (e.Action)
    {
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add when e.NewItems != null:
        // Check if insert or add
        verticalOffset = e.NewStartingIndex < this.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset 
          ?  this.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset + e.NewItems.Count 
          : this.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove when e.OldItems != null:
        verticalOffset = this.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.OldItems.Count;
        break;
      default:
        verticalOffset = this.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        break;
    }

    this.ScrollViewer?.ScrollToVerticalOffset(verticalOffset);
  }


  #endregion

  public bool TryFindVisualChildElement<TChild>(DependencyObject parent, out TChild childElement)
    where TChild : FrameworkElement
  {
    childElement = null;
    if (parent == null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
      if (child is TChild resultElement)
      {
        childElement = resultElement;
        return true;
      }

      if (TryFindVisualChildElement(child, out childElement))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

The class can be enhanced by making the behavior optional e.g., by introducing an enum.

Comment: Hello. With your sample code, i can't make new instance of Window.
Window tmpWindow = new Window();
tmpWindow.Show() -> Error occured, nullPointExceotion..

Comment: this.ScrollViewer?.ScrollToVerticalOffset(this.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset + e.NewItems.Count);
in this code occur some error, And e.NewItems.Count is null when i make new Window

Comment: And,, i insert try-catch then i can see the Window, but it is not work with my intend..

Comment: This is a minimal code example. Obviously you need to check `e.NewItems == null`. I have updated the example. It should work now. In case you are overriding the `ControlTemplate` of the control, don't forget to add a `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: @charleskim Sorry, I have edited the answer but forgot to post the changes. I've done it right now. I have also improved the previous code and added the handling of item removal. This control now keeps the current viewport in position on item(s) inserted or removed.

Comment: Thanks for your Help! But it isn't work for me. it operate like Just ListBox to me. When i insert object like "insert(0, object)" still my screen move also. And i override ListBoxItem, not ListBox

Comment: I have tested the code and it works perfectly for insert, add and remove. And why are you extending `ListBoxItem`? How is this supposed to work? `ListBoxItem` even hasn't a `ScrollViewer`. You must use my code. Don't do something else and then say the posted code doesn't work. Doesn't make sense, you must admit. You must extend `ListBox` as this is the control that handles the items and hosts the `ScrollViewer`. It works 100%.

Comment: In case you override the `ControlTemplate` of `ListBox`, make sure you add the `ScrollViewer`. If you still have problems, please post your current implementation and how  you use the `KeepItemsInViewListBox`, so that we can find the mistake.

Comment: OK mr.Code i will try it with new Empty mvvm project and back here then say you are right!

Comment: Mr.Code you are Right really!. i'm wrong... so sorry. i tested your Class with empty project, it worked perfectly. then i should find what is wrong.

Comment: Mr. Kim, don't worry. If you need help, please read my last comment. Sometimes it helps to clear and then rebuild the solution.

Comment: Mr.Code,   With ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll = "False" your Class is not work.
i think your code make ScrollViewer to scrolling by item. but my all of listboxItem's size is diffrent each other.

Comment: please visit this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843335/wpf-listbox-item-by-item-scrolling-to-pixel-based-scrolling